# Finding a "good date" which has two or fewer different digits with an additional requirement

Tags: python, algorithm, date, datetime

I have a coding problem with determining a "good date" (more description below).

I solved the original problem but got stuck on the follow-up problem. I attached my questions and solution to the original problem below. Thank you for your help in advance.

##### Original Problem:

> YYYY/MM/DD format is a notation of date consisting of the zero-padded
> 4-digit year, zero-padded 2-digit month, and zero-padded 2-digit day,
> separated by slashes.
>
> A good date has two or fewer different digits in
> YYYY/MM/DD format.
>
> Given a date `S` in YYYY/MM/DD format. Print the first good day
> **not earlier** than `S`, in YYYY/MM/DD format. `S` is between January 1, 2001 and December 31, 2999 (inclusive).

> Ex. `2022/01/01` gives `2022/02/02` and `2999/12/31` gives `3000/03/03`.

#### Follow-up (stuck):

> Find the closest good date instead; it can be either earlier or later
> than `S`.

#### My Questions:

1. Is there a better way to solve the original problem? I used a triple loop, so...
2. How can I tackle the follow-up problem? I can only think of finding all good dates and comparing them to `S`...

#### My Solution to the Original Problem:

```py
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def good_date(s: str) -> str:
        s = ''.join(s.split("/"))
        starting_year = eval(s + ' // 10000')

        for yyyy in range(starting_year, 3001):
            for mm in range(1, 13):
                for dd in range(1, 32):

                    date = str(yyyy) + f"{mm:02}" + f"{dd:02}"

                    if len(set(date)) == 2 and s <= date:
                        return date[:4] + "/" + date[4:6] + "/" + date[6:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = input()
    print(Solution.good_date(S))
```

Comment: The title say "two or fewer digits" but you test for ==2. And 3001/03/03 is outside the limit. You should clarify and edit your question.

Comment: Using eval() to do a division is a very bad habit.

Comment: `S` is the input. The problem has no constraint (in the original problem, it has to be at a later date) on the output.

Comment: *"S is between January 1, 2001 and December 31, 2999 (inclusive)."*. Thus you already know that the year contains digit `2`. Thus the only months allowed are 02,11,12. And thus the only days allowed are 01, 02, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22.

Comment: Also, your three nested loops will run through every day of every months of every year, even though for most years there are obviously no solutions. For instance, year 2010 doesn't have any solution, so you should skip it entirely. Only years 2002, 2020, 2022, 2111, 2112, 2121, 2122, 2200, 2202, 2211, 2212, 2322, 2323, 2332, 2333, etc., can have solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can reduce them to `for mm in range(2, 13)` and `for dd in range(1, 23)`

Comment: Why `range(2,13)`? That's way more than needed. Just do `for mm in (2, 11, 12):` and `for dd in (1,2,11,12,20,21,22):`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250692/discussion-between--and-stef).

Comment: The question do not specify if the non-significant zero digit in month and day must be significant in number of different digits. 2222-01-12, for example, would be valid or not., depending on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the data size is small, you may consider to test by brute force which can solve both original problem and the follow up one.

**Conceptually**, consider the digit(s) to be used and form a set of choices:

{0, 1, 2, ... 9, 01, 02, 03 ..., 09, 12, 13 ... 99 }

The size of the set is small: 10 single digits choice + 10C2 = 55 choices in total.

We can form all possible dates with these choices and compare with the given date.

**Implementation:**

Single digit is straight forward, for example: 0000/00/00, 1111/11/11 .....

For 2 digits, for example 0 and 1, you can simply use recursive backtracking to generate possible dates, such as 0000/00/01, 0000/01/10 ... etc.

For each date, check if the date is valid date and compare with the input to get the closest answer.

**Psuedo Code**:

```
 // Generate 2 digit choices by any means ~ O(10^2)
 // Method 1: two for-loops
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++) for(int j=i+1; j<10; j++) choices.add({i, j});
 // Method 2: bitmask
 for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) 
     if( i has exactly 2 one-bit in binary expression ) 
         choices.add({the index of the one-bit });

 // Backtracking ~ O(2^8)
 void dfs(choice, date, len){
    if(len == 8) {
        check_if_valid_date(date);
        compare_with_input_and_update_answer(date);
        return;
    }
    date += choice_1st_digit;
    dfs(choice, date, len+1);

    date -= choice_1st_digit;
    date += choice_2nd_digit;
    dfs(choice, date, len+1);
 }

 for(all choice in choices){
     dfs(choice, "", 0);
 }

 // Total Complexity ~ O(10^2 * 2^8) which is fast enough in every modern machines
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer コリン's comment:
Think about the job your 'eval' solution has to do:

- concatenate 2 strings
- in eval():

  - split the string into 3 tokens
  - detect it is an integer division
  - convert 2 numbers to binary (using int)
  - do integer division
  - return value

It would be lighter to use:

```
starting_year = int( s[0:4])
```

And I mention "bad habit" because it's dangerous to use eval() with user input. For example, if user enter '1/(1-1)' as a date, it will crash your program. But he(she) may even do worse. Every time input() is used, it should be sanitized and it's critical if the input is sent to eval().

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also read some articles about vulnerability on eval(). It’s indeed a bad habit. The string slice is much cleaner as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a single-level loop.
It take care of leap years and irregular days_per_month.
And you can easily modify number of different_digits and end_date.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def next_good_date( udate:date)->date:
    day_duration = timedelta( days=1)
    while True:
        udate += day_duration
        #udate_asc = f"{udate.year}{udate.month}{udate.day}" # use if leading zeros are non-significant
        udate_asc = f"{udate.year:04}{udate.month:02}{udate.day:02}" # use if leading zeros are significant
        if len( set( udate_asc)) <= 2:
            return udate
        if udate == date.fromisoformat( '3000-01-01'): return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    udate = date.fromisoformat( input( "date(yyyy/mm/dd)> ").replace('/','-')) # ISO use '-'
    udate = next_good_date( udate)
    if udate:
        print( udate.strftime( "%Y/%m/%d"))
    else:
        print( "No answer")
```

There are 88 good_date inside the specified date range and the last one is 2222/12/22
It will be easy to create 'previous_good_date()' using 'next_good_date()' as a model.

Comment: `2002/02/22` should return `2002/02/22` as the input is already a "good date."

Comment: OK. You can do it by moving line "udate += day_duration" as last statement of the loop. Do you prefer I do it?